# C# Display images in ListView vertically

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to figure out a way of creating a vertical, large icons ListView, then add items that contain a bitmap at the left side, and description at right side, i looked on options but i couldn't find anything related to what i need, i am a C# newbie and i don't know if it's truly possible to do it with the built-in options.

I do not know how many items i will load, as the application will be constantly checking for new server responses and i'd like to add new responses constantly to the ListView.

I am able to get the image and description from the web and create a bitmap using the image, but i couldn't figure a way to create the listview properly and add the items in the code below.

```
var Message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
var Con = new SocketCommandContext(Client, Message);
WebRequest request =
    WebRequest.Create(Con.Message.Author.GetAvatarUrl());
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream =
    response.GetResponseStream();
Avatar = new Bitmap(responseStream);
string Message = Con.Message.Content;
```

I need something like

[image]

EDIT: I tried this:

```
foreach (IGuild guild in Guilds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting Guild: "+ guild.Name);
            WebRequest request =
            WebRequest.Create(guild.IconUrl);
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Icon WebRequest for: " +guild.Name);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Getting Icon WebRequest response for: " +guild.Name);

            Stream responseStream =
                response.GetResponseStream();
            GuildAvatar = new Bitmap(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine("Adding Guild " + guild.Name + " to Guild list for user " + Client.CurrentUser.Username);
            AvatarCache.Images.Add(guild.Name, GuildAvatar);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully transformed bitmap to icon");
            Console.WriteLine("Inmediatly adding Guild to list");
            var GuildItem = listView2.Items.Add(guild.Name);
            GuildItem.ImageKey = guild.Name;
            Console.WriteLine("Added guild: " + guild.Name);
        }
        materialFlatButton1.Text = "Connected";
```

but it returns just after the "Inmediatly adding Guild to list" line, and it does not show any type of exception in the studio when debugging, however if i remove the "Item.Add" line, it will end the code correctly and change button text.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Consider adding a tag for either [tag:winforms], [tag:wpf] or [tag:asp.net] to assist people understanding the scenario, since it's not clear from the question.

Comment: The code you posted is not related to the question.

Comment: The code i posted is the one i use to get the avatar from the web, and i would like to add the avatar i downloaded to the listview, along with the message.

Comment: Where is the problem? If the icons are 256x256 or less and all have the same size you can stuff them into an ImageList. If not you may need to owner-draw the LV. Lots of examples for both..

Comment: Taw, the problem is that i do not have any icons, only bitmaps.

Comment: The other problem is that isn't possible to create vertical listviews containing bitmaps and descriptions in the settings

Comment: Since you have a Bitmap, you can store it in an `ImageList`, then use the `ImageSize` property to resize it to `Min(1;1) => Max(256;256)`. With any measure in between. I think you have a `64x64` one in your sample image here. You know what to do (and yes, you can have Bitmaps, description and checkboxes without any *special treatment*. Vanilla `ListView`.

Comment: Resizing is not needed cause all images downloaded come in default with 128x128, the main problem is that they dont seem to work in ListView

Comment: *they don't seem to work* has no actual meaning. Use the Debugger. Insert a breakpoint in `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`, step-debug the code, inspecting each object (check it's not null, read it's internal values), property, field, variable while is assigned, read and printed.

Comment: For what it's worth and as far as I could tell from the code you've shown, this seems to work for me. Assuming AvatarCache is an ImageList type, listView2.SmallImageList is set to AvatarCache, listView2's View property is set to View.SmallIcon, AND guild.Name is NOT null nor empty.